# Transform problem with rviz map display when using the SLAMTEC Mapper M2M2 with ROS

Tags: slam, lidar, rviz, ros-noetic

I am working on a project using the SLAMTEC Mapper M2M2 with ROS to map an area of interest. I am using Oracle Virtualbox to run ROS Noetic with Ubuntu 20.04, and my host machine is running on Windows 10. However, when running rviz, there seems to be a problem with the map display. Below is what I did from the beginning.

After downloading the Slamware ROS SDK (GCC 9) from the SLAMTEC website, I moved the folders to the src folder in my catkin_ws. I connected the device to a power bank, and then connected my PC to its built-in WiFi. After that, I launched the relevant nodes in the 'slamware_ros_sdk' package as follows.

```
roslaunch slamware_ros_sdk slamware_ros_sdk_server_node.launch ip_address:=192.168.11.1

roslaunch slamware_ros_sdk view_slamware_ros_sdk_server_node.launch
```

Everything seems to be working fine, the map of the area of interest can be viewed, however, there is a status error in the map display under transform. The error is as follows.

> No transform from [/slamware_map] to [slamware_map].

Because of this, I am unable to view the location of the device within the map generated (the axes are located outside of the map). I also cannot save the map in a pgm file via the map_server package. Maybe this is due to the map not being generated properly. I attached a picture below.

[image: Map display status error in rviz]

I am just using the SLAMTEC Mapper on its own, without any other devices or robots, as I just require the map to work with.

Would appreciate any help and support I can get. Apologies as I am still new to ROS, so I might not know a lot of things.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

> No transform from [/slamware_map] to [slamware_map].

I'm not familiar with Slamware in particular, but I can tell you what the error means. RViz is trying to display data that has a `frame_id` of `/slamware_map` in a frame with id `slamware_map`. It does not see these as the same (or related) frames because one of them has a leading `/` and one does not. This might mean that your map topic and your `/tf` topic disagree on the frame name.

The simplest resolution for you is probably to modify the code that's producing the data, so all nodes are using the exact same `frame_id`. It could also be related to the setting of [fixed frame](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Coordinate_Frames) that you've chosen in RViz, so make sure to check that too.

You can read a (very old) post about leading slashes and prefixes in ROS here: https://answers.ros.org/question/43145/tf-namespace-resolution/

And on the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration

See also: https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/219 "There should not be a slash."

Comment: Thank you very much